# how set/get data from Raspberry Pi to server

Tags: php, python, database, raspberry-pi, iot

HIHello everyone
I have a Raspberry Pi that contain some data,
on another side, I have a server with a server, also there is a webpage connecting with the same server.
what do I need? 
1- the Raspberry Pi must send its data to a server 
2-if the user set some data to the database by webpage the Raspberry Pi must get this data 
3-Raspberry Pi must listen to the database to know if there is an update or not.
what the best way to do these points, is there any protocol for IoT can do these? 
I need any hint :) 
thank u for all.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a php tool to access a (mysql) database.

Comment: ad1: the pi has to call a script on the server to save the sent data into database.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the server

Comment: ad2: if you cannot call your pi from your server (what I suppose because of dynamic ip) make the pi check every 5 minutes for new data.

Comment: _"is there any protocol for IoT"_ - http should be the easiest to implement...

Comment: thanks, Jeff, I was thinking about sending a single byte to the server as the question "is there any update", but Livestream stopped me I am looking now for the best protocol to establish a connection with the server.
 I have multiple Raspberry Pi in the same network so I cannot use TCP 
is the HTTP can return data from server?
if I send a message to the server and server found any update in the database can it return these date as a response to specific Raspberry Pi that had been sent this message

Comment: Maybe you should explain what is your use case and what have you done so far? The Raspberry Pi can be a web server that allows user to input data on the website, and process it and save it to a database. Are you having the problem on the web server part or on the database management part?

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your RPi with your server through any means of local area connection, it could be a connection through a wifi network or using a lan cable or even through serial ports. If successful in this attempt then you can access disk drive folders inside the server. In the webpage running on server ,make it listen for certain values and write the status to a text file or an database. Then make RPi to continuously monitor those file for data updation and make it work according to it.

Comment: "make it listen" can u give me more details, listen to Database is available? i though there is no way to listen to MySQL

Comment: create a thread to continuously monitor the database values and if any change is present make a routine corresponding to it